# NodeJS: Can't connect to postgreSQL container from another container

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker

I have container with a NodeJS application and it has to be linked to another container with a Postgres db. My `docker-compose.yml` is:

```
version: "3"
services:
  postgres:
    image: "postgres:9.5.6-alpine"
    container_name: postgres
    volumes:
      - /shared_folder/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"  
  web:
    build: .  
    container_name: web
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - postgres 
    depends_on:
      - postgres 
    command: sh /usr/home/freebsd/wait-for-command.sh -c 'nc -z postgres 5432' 
    command: sh start.sh
```

On postgres container there is a db named "bucket", owned by user "user" with password "password".

When I type docker-compose up, and try to link the containers, after this message from console:

```
[INFO] console - postgres://user:password@localhost:5432/bucket
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Connection terminated
at [object Object].<anonymous>
```

in `/node_modules/massive/node_modules/deasync/index.js:46`

where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You define `command` twice, which means your `wait-for-command.sh` is being overridden by `sh start.sh` and it's probably being run before PostgreSQL is ready to accept connections.